# wordpress shortcode wrapping

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I’d like to take a few Wordpress shortcodes that I use (from 3rd party plugins) and "wrap" them in a different looking button.

Basically, I want to take: `[ld_notes_button]` which renders an ugly button that I have little control over, and turn it into an icon that people can click and it will still bring up the notes field like the original button would.

I have very little experience with coding stuff like this, so I’d appreciate any help!

Comment: please show us some code where you have attempted to do this.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I haven’t attempted yet, I have no idea if it’s even possible and wouldn’t know where to start... that’s why I’m asking ;)